# python - get all child elements inside html tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <main>
        <div>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
   </main>

    <section>
        <article>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
       </article>
</section>
</body>
```

I'm trying to find the TAG with the most child tags element level 1
output: "article"

basically I'm trying to find the element tag with the most content inside random URL.

Comment: Can you please show what code you're currently trying with?

Answer (score 0):

best idea I could think of is to get the class with the most content inside of it

def get_links_inside_url(url):

```
"""

"""

page = urlopen( url ).read()   #getting the whole html souorce raw (unclear)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml") #getting the whole html souorce raw (clear)

d = {}

classes = []
for element in soup.find_all(class_=True):
    classes.extend(element["class"])


for cls in classes:

    class_content = soup.body.find(attrs={'class':cls})

    if class_content and ';' not in class_content.text and len(class_content.text) > 100:

        char_in_class = len(class_content.text)
        print(char_in_class)
        if cls not in d :
            d[cls] = char_in_class
        else:
            d[cls] += char_in_class


return d
```